# Adding suggestion List in SearchView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, searchview

I want to make a suggestion list while typing in SearchView located in the toolbar ! Suggestion to word displayed in the listView 
SearchView created following the official site to android developer

The **Menu Item**:
And here is part of my **Main Activity** :
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
    int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
        }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);}
```

This part of **a fragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_layout, container, false);
    listView  = (ListView)   rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView12);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    getJSON();
    return rootview;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what should i do :
Will I work in the MainActvity or in each Fragment used in my navigation drawer, 
Any suggestions will be great ho to do this 
Thank you for all suggestions.